# [ROS2]Are there any examples of tf2 broadcast or listener

Tags: ros, ros2, tf2-ros, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello comrades, I`m just trying to get odometry from t265 from realsense2_lib examples. After compiling and running this code below, I get that *target frame* does not exist.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include <rclcpp/time_source.hpp>
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/pose_stamped.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/pose_stamped.hpp>
#include <tf2_ros/buffer_interface.h>
#include <tf2_ros/visibility_control.h>
#include <tf2/buffer_core.h>
#include <tf2/time.h>
#include <tf2_ros/buffer.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/transform_stamped.h>
/* We do not recommend this style anymore, because composition of multiple
 * nodes in the same executable is not possible. Please see one of the subclass
 * examples for the "new" recommended styles. This example is only included
 * for completeness because it is similar to "classic" standalone ROS nodes. */

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("tf_pub");
  auto publisher = node->create_publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>("tf_pub", 10);

  //printf("TimePoint %d",tp);
//  std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Clock> clock_ptr;
  rclcpp::Clock::SharedPtr clock = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Clock>(RCL_ROS_TIME);
  rclcpp::TimeSource timesource;
  timesource.attachClock(clock);

//  tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer(clock_ptr);
  std::unique_ptr<tf2_ros::Buffer> buffer = nullptr;




  tf2::Transform transform_;
  transform_.setIdentity();
  buffer = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::Buffer>(clock);

  geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped message;
  rclcpp::WallRate loop_rate(500ms);

  while (rclcpp::ok()) {

    try {

        geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped transformStamped = buffer->lookupTransform("odom_frame", "camera_link", tf2::TimePointZero);
        message.pose.position.x = transformStamped.transform.translation.x;
        message.pose.position.y = transformStamped.transform.translation.y;
        RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "Publishing: '%s'", message.pose);
        publisher->publish(message);
    }
    catch (tf2::TransformException & ex) {
          RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "StaticLayer: %s", ex.what());
    }


    rclcpp::spin_some(node);
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338515/%5Bros2%5Dare-there-any-examples-of-tf2-broadcast-or-listener/) by [Sol](https://answers.ros.org/users/31466/sol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) on 2019-11-25**:
This probably doesn't help, but we did push a big set of changes to the documentation and how to's for Eloquent. [Check them out here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/).

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2019-11-27**:
The code looks okay to me. Are you sure that the target frame (`"odom_frame"`) does indeed exist?
You can confirm by running `ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_monitor odom_frame camera_link`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I had same trouble with lookup_transform. I'm found solution in tf_echo  [source code](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/ros2/tf2_ros/src/tf2_echo.cpp).
You need add tf2_ros::TransformListener and init it with tf2_ros::Buffer:

```
std::unique_ptr<tf2_ros::Buffer> buffer = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::Buffer>(node->get_clock());
std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::TransformListener> transform_listener_ = std::make_shared<tf2_ros::TransformListener>(*tf_buffer_);
```

Now when I call lookupTransform() it works as expected. I hope this helps you.

---

Originally posted by [georgiy](https://answers.ros.org/users/23586/georgiy/) with karma: 76 on 2020-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, we don't have any nice, succinct examples, but I think it would be good if we port the [tf2 tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials) to ROS 2.

I know RViz makes use of `tf2_ros::TransformListener` as part of the [TFWrapper class](https://github.com/ros2/rviz/blob/045227a9fc251ab9e5af763bddc1f203aff6feac/rviz_default_plugins/include/rviz_default_plugins/transformation/tf_wrapper.hpp).

The [AmclNode class](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/0154951f9cbeab9b5272f36ed02d65b25fdda0f4/nav2_amcl/include/nav2_amcl/amcl_node.hpp) also uses `tf2_ros::TransformListener` as well as `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster`.
I'm sure there's other instances of them being used in the wild that others might be able to point you to.

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2019-11-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Almost](https://answers.ros.org/users/28007/almost/) on 2020-07-15**:
From the description of tf2_ros I understand that this package is for ROS and roscpp, not ROS2. So why is it being used with ROS2? Isn't that some abomination?

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-07-15**:
I think "port" is a better word than "abomination", haha.

tf2_ros is a set of ROS bindings for the tf2 library. Since the [ROS 1 implementation](https://github.com/ros/geometry2/tree/noetic-devel/tf2_ros) proved very useful to robot makers, there exists a [ROS 2 port](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/tree/ros2/tf2_ros). Since the client libraries for ROS 1 and ROS 2 are significantly different (roscpp vs rclcpp), we can expect the respective tf2_ros bindings to look different. This is why we currently maintain a separate ROS 2 version of tf2_ros, as the implementation diverges from the original.

**Comment by [Almost](https://answers.ros.org/users/28007/almost/) on 2020-07-15**:
I understand why you would separate some interface to make the code maintenance easier. But I still don't see why it is not all in tf2:: namespace, or always tf2:: for ros2 and tf2_ros for ros. Now I even see ros2 code that uses both. I am sorry, I don't know the architecture and it just doesn't make sense to me.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-07-15**:
The differences in namespaces are coming from different packages in the [geometry2](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2) repository. There is a package named `tf2`, which is ROS-agnostic. ROS-specific bindings/features are provided by a different package `tf2_ros` (which depends on `tf2`). The different namespaces, `tf2::` and `tf2_ros::`, are named after the package where the API is coming from. To clarify, this is the same package/namespace structure used in both ROS 1 and ROS 2.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-07-15**:
So, in theory, a single version of `tf2` could be maintained and used by multiple versions of `tf2_ros` (but I think for historical reasons and convenience, we have separate versions of all `geometry2` packages for ROS 1 and ROS 2).